# Add an Office365 user to the Role Group "View-Only Organization Management"

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to add an Office365 User to the Role-Group, "**View-Only Organization Management**" from client side using C# and PowerShell. I have installed the [Azure AD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx) on my local machine. After which, I am able to run the following cmdlets both from PowerShell as well as my Console app:

- Connect-MsolService
- New-MsolUser
- Add-MSOLRoleMember

Now, to add the User, to the Role-Group, "**View-Only Organization Management**", I tried to use the cmdlet, [Add-RoleGroupMember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638207(v=exchg.150).aspx) in the format,

```
Add-RoleGroupMember "View-Only Organization Management" -Member PK
```

**PK** is the display name of the User. But when I execute this cmdlet from PowerShell or my Console app, I am getting the following error:

[image: Error Img]

So how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that none of the "**Exchange 2013**" cmdlet will not be present on our machine by default., We need to import the Powershell Session before using the cmdlet and then to remove it when we're done using it. Below is the complete set of commands needed to perform this task:

Open Windows Powershell.

Get the credentials.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
```

[image]

Create a remote PowerShell session

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
```

Plz make sure that the url given above is for Exchange Online only.
[image]

Import the cmdlets to the PowerShell

```
Import-PSSession $Session
```

[image]
[image]

Once the import is done, all the [Exchange 2013 cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124413(v=exchg.150).aspx) become available.

We can then execute the cmdlet, "**Add-RoleGroupMember**"

```
Add-RoleGroupMember -identity "View-Only Organization Management" -member PKS
```

Finally, don't forget to remove the Session before exiting.

```
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

[image]

The only difference was that earlier I was not importing the PSSession before executing this cmdlet. Plz note that import is valid for any Exchange 2013 cmdlet and not just for this only.

For further details, you can visit [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.150).aspx).